# how to replace multiple leading space, each space with a specific char, in vscode interactively?

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to replace multiple leading space, each space with a specific char, in vscode?
FROM:

```
abcd
 bcd
  cd
   d
```

TO:

```
abcd
_bcd
__cd
___d
```

Comment: select the first space and then `Ctrl+D` to select next and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D` to skip current

Comment: then type `_` when all are selected

Comment: only for leading space, man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it "interactively":

Find: `^\s|(?<=_)\s`
Replace: `_`

1. Enter those find/replace in the Find widget first.
2. Select the lines you want to work on.
3. Enable the `Find in Selection` option on the Find widget.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will progressively add the underscores.

[image: replace spaces with underscore]